# RDFlib (python): freeing memory from the graph

Tags: python, memory, rdflib

I am declaring my graph as follows, which defines it in memory:

```
import rdflib as rdf
g = rdf.Graph()  # create the RDF graph
```

then populate it with my triples and finally serialise it to a file as follows:

```
g.serialize(destination=filename)
```

Two questions:

1. if now I would loop back and repeat the g = RDFlib.Graph() instruction, would the memory be freed/reused and not just added?
2. Is there a way to explicitly free the memory occupied by g ?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Python provides a del function to free memory of a variable, therefore you just need to code:

```
del g
```

and g will not exist anymore